# Python - Use same socket in multiple functions

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to use a python socket across multiple functions, but i'm not sure how. I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyBattle.py", line 169, in <module>
    client()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyBattle.py", line 157, in client
    clientWait()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyBattle.py", line 107, in clientWait
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Here's a section of the client function:

```
def client():
    print "Enter server IP."
    TCP_IP = raw_input(">")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
```

Here's the clientWait function:

```
def clientWait():
    os.system("cls")
    print "Not your turn."
    print "Username:" + username + " HP:" + str(hp) + " Level:" + str(level) + " Attack:" + str(attack) + " Defence:" + str(defence) + " Speed:" + str(speed)
    print "Opponent:" + opponentUsername + " HP:" + str(opponentHp) + " Level:" + str(opponentLevel) + " Attack:" + str(opponentAttack) + " Defence:" + str(opponentDefence) + " Speed:" + str(opponentSpeed)
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    clientProcess()
```

I believe it's to do with the fact that the socket isn't global? Thanks for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your error isn't specifically because the socket isn't "global".  It's because the `s` you're referring to in your `clientWait` function isn't the local variable `s` in your `client` function.  You've created it elsewhere (and haven't shown us where).

Please don't make your socket "global".  Just return if from your `client` function, and pass it into your `clientWait` function.

You should probably look into restructuring your code in terms of [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), and making most of your variables [instance variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).  It looks like you're using global variables throughout which will make your program brittle, hard to understand, hard to test, hard to document, etc..

Comment: After looking at my code, I realised I had created the socket outside of the client and clientWait functions. Lines 4 - 7 of the pastebin link i will provide demonstrate this. I have commented them out, and was met with the error NameError: global name 's' is not defined. I still, however, have no idea on how to fix this. Full code here: http://pastebin.com/x2qh1mXQ

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I had to do was declare s as global before giving it a value. So:

```
global s
s = ...
```

Thanks again for all the answers, and thank you Gerrat for the help.